# CSS putting an item on the right side of a grid

Tags: html, css

I would like to put the button(containing 14) on the right end of the division.
I tried justify content end
But it's not working.
I set the background color to gray, so it's easier to see.
My code is below.
Thanks in advance.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Exercise 12a</title>
    <style>
      .line-div {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 300px 80px;
        align-items: center;
        width: 300px;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .left-div{
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 19px;
      margin-left:15px;
      background-color: gray;
      }
      .description{
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      .right-div{
       background-color: gray;
       vertical-align: middle;
       justify-items: end;
      }
      .number{
        background-color: rgb(0, 89, 255);
        border-style: none;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: white;
        padding-left: 13px;
        padding-right: 13px;
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        border-radius: 13px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="line-div">
      <div class="left-div"><p class="description">Home</p></div>
      <div class="right-div">
        <button class="number">14</button>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're only trying to use grid, but in my experience flex and grid work great together. I would simply do this:

```css
.right-div{
       background-color: gray;
       vertical-align: middle;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: flex-end;
      }
```

But if you wanted to keep it as grid:

```css
.right-div{
       display: grid;
       background-color: gray;
       vertical-align: middle;
       justify-items: end;
      }
```